# Can having domain reg. + hosting with the same company make for a faster loading website?

Tags: webserver, web-hosting, domains, domain-registrar

Curious to know if there is / can be any slowdown from having one's domain name registered with one company, but hosted with another.

I'm guessing the answer is either:

- "Not necessarily", given that hosting companies have many choices about how to set things up
- Or maybe "not at all", given the nature of the relationship between hosing and domain names

But there's a lot I don't know about this realm.

Comment: Slightly off the original question, as the owner of a web hosting business I can assure you that having registration and hosting with the one company can save hassles.  I am constantly helping people who don't know where their domain is registered or have forgotten the login or are just confused by the whole system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't be any faster if the two are served by the same company.  There are no opportunity for synergies between the domain registration, DNS, and web services.  They don't use the same protocols, they don't use the same ports, they don't use the same types of servers.   There isn't going to be an opportunity for any type of caching or reuse between the two.

I use separate companies for:

- DNS Registration
- DNS hosting
- Web services
- Email hosting

You can choose each for its own merits (speed, price, reliability, service) without effecting the speeds of the others.

You may find that there are bundles that give you good deals when you use two or more of those services from the same company, but you won't find any speed advantages.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming what I expected. Curious, do you have any resource(s) that might help describe this relationship further?

Comment: It's common knowledge @Drewdavid, I wouldn't expect to find any sources for this. The answer is most likely provided from knowing how networks work. The only speed factor is the resolve of DNS from domain to IP.

Answer (score 0):

Speed is totally diff. aspect and mechanism. Basically speed is depends on following :

1 - How you construct your website
2 - What web standard you follow
3 - your site resource loading priority
4 - 3rd party resource use
5 - Standard and optimized code

There are other lot of things which are related with loading speed.

so in concern of your question , My answer is option **"No at all"**

Hope our help removed your big misunderstanding of domain + hosting about speed.

Answer (score 0):

No, domain and hosting need not to be from same company and there is no connection of speed of website with domain company. Speed does depend on hosting company, DNS resolution, server specs, bandwidth, no. of hits, page size, page code and various other factors but not domain registrar.